# Excel formula replace remaining characters with spaces

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to concatenate the value of all columns or each row from sheet 1 to sheet 2, but in every columns from sheet 1 has an allotted characters so whether it is blank or not filled completely it will consume the same amount of spaces into the output sheet.

> Example of my desired output:
>
> Sheet 1 (Input)
>
> Allotted characters per column: ID Number (4), Balance (7), OR Number (5), Account Name (10), Reference Code (5)
>
> |---ID Number---|---Balance---|---OR Number---|---Account Name---|---Reference Code---|
>
> |------- 003 -------|- 5,000,000 -|------ 12345 ------|---- Transports -----|--------- 11123 ----------|
>
> |------- 010 ------|---- 5,000 ----|------ 31234 ------|----- Human A ------|----------- 121 -----------|
>
> |------- 33 --------|--------  --------|------ 56567 ------|------ Testing --------|----------- 54321 --------|
>
> |------- 111 ------|------- 7 -------|------------ ----------|----- Human B ------|----------- 21 ------------|

```
Sheet 2 (Output) 

003500000012345Transports11123
010   500031234   Human A  121 
 33       56567   Testing54321
111      7        Human B   21
```

My current formula just leave the spaces if the cell  is empty, I dont know if there is a code for excel to replace the remaining spaces with blank characters.

```
=IF(A10="","",
IF(LEFT(A10,1)="T","",
IF(Input!A11<>"",
IF(Input!A11=""," ",Input!A11)&
IF(Input!B11="","   Input! ",Input!B11)&
IF(Input!C11="","      ",Input!C11)&
IF(Input!D11="","      ",Input!D11)&
IF(Input!E11="","      ",Input!E11)&
IF(Input!F11="","      ",Input!F11)&
IF(Input!G11="","            ",Input!G11)&
IF(Input!H11="","          ",Input!H11)&
IF(Input!I11="","          ",Input!I11)&
IF(Input!J11="","      ",Input!J11)&
IF(Input!K11="","          ",Input!K11)&
IF(Input!L11="","                              ",Input!L11)&
IF(Input!M11="","      ",Input!M11)&
IF(Input!N11="","          ",Input!N11)&
IF(Input!O11="","   ",Input!O11)&
IF(Input!P11="","   ",Input!P11)&
IF(Input!Q11="","          ",Input!Q11)&
IF(Input!R11="","            ",Input!R11)&
IF(Input!S11="","         ",Input!S11),"T"&MIN(ROW(A11:A12))+ROWS(A11)-3&"   "&SUM(Input!H:H))))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `RIGHT(REPT(" ",99)&D11,10)` instead of the `IF(Input!D11="","      ",Input!D11)` bit for instance

Comment: @AntiDrondert My example desired output is what I showed on the sheet 2 above. my current formula just leave a certain amount of spaces if the cell is null.

Comment: @YowE3K I am not very familiar with excel, so can you explain how does that formula works? RIGHT(REPT(" ",99)&D11,10)

Comment: `REPT(" ",99)` repeats `" "` 99 times.  That is then concatenated to the value from D11 so, if D11 contained "Human A" then you would have 99 spaces followed by "Human A".  `RIGHT(...,10)` takes the rightmost 10 characters, thus giving `"   Human A"`.  (There's three spaces before that "H", although it's not so obvious in comments.)  But the best way to find out what something does is type it into Excel and see what happens.

Comment: @YowE3K I get it now! I use this `=REPT(" ",6-LEN(A4))&A4&REPT(" ",6-LEN(B4))&B4&REPT(" ",6-LEN(C4))&C4` thanks for your help!

Comment: You would need to change those `6`s to be `4`, `7`, and `5` but, yes, that would work too.  (Except when a field is larger than the allocated space, in which case that method would break.)

Comment: @YowE3K yes sir, I am trying to have a fixed length so this works fine with me. Thanks to your help again.